# WCF queue behavior for MaxConcurrentCalls

Tags: wcf, webhttpbinding

I have a WCF service with the following settings:

- Binding = WebHttpBinding
- InstanceContextMode = Single
- ConcurrencyMode = Multiple
- MaxConcurrentSessions = a high value

The documentation states about MaxConcurrentCalls: the MaxConcurrentCalls property specifies the maximum number of messages actively processing across a ServiceHost object. Each channel can have one pending message that does not count against the value of MaxConcurrentCalls until begins to process it.

Several questions:

- What does the sentence "Each channel can have one pending message that does not count against the value of MaxConcurrentCalls until begins to process it" exactly mean?
- If the MaxConcurrentCalls tresshold is reached, are new TCP connections queued?
- If the MaxConcurrentCalls tresshold is reached, are new requests on existing TCP connections queued (during pipe-lining)?
- How to specify the length of those queues?

Thanks!

Rene